# What's the source of the sound that's heard when I connect a phone to my PC?

Tags: windows-10, audio

My phone jack is somewhat damaged. It disconnects and reconnects with little movement. I don't really have a problem with this. What I have a problem with is the connection sound the Windows makes whenever it reconnects.

I turned down the volume of `System Sounds` to hell, in volume mixer. It didn't help with this. What's the source of this connection sound and/or how do I disable or at least turn it down a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They tend to be located in `C:\Windows\Media`

Another way to find out is by going into your sound settings like so:

---

1. Right click the volumn icon on the right of your taskbar and choose `Sounds`.

[image]

2. Go into the `Sounds` tab and find the sound named "**Device Connect**"

[image]

---

From here you can choose from a list of pre existing sounds or browse for a new one.

If you are looking to disable it though, you could scroll to the top in the drop down menu and choose `(None)`